# Prevent notifications to be read by other apps

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am making a security-based app. And need to prevent other apps from reading push or other notifications created by this app.

When this app is creating a notification, can we somehow block other 3rd party apps to read their notifications that appear in the notification bar?

For example, any 3rd party app has access to notifications of other apps and can read them. And I want to block other apps from reading the notification so when the notification from my apps comes, no other apps will be able to "see" it.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? "any 3rd party app has access to notifications of other apps and can read them" - this isn't true, only apps where the user has explicitly consented to notification access can do this.

Comment: @RyanMentley A kind of specific use case for the app. An app has to inform its users of some event using notifications, but we must be sure that no other apps can fetch this notification and read it. Yes, quite unusual, but it's a use case that we have to implement.

Comment: How you found the solution. Please post answer if resolved.